# Why boost library with wrong toolset is searched while linking?

Tags: c++, boost

I am building one project and that project is expecting boost libraries. I compiled boost library 1_70 in VS2017 and library files has been generated. I am building my project with VS2017, so my toolset is V141. But while linking compiler is expecting for V140.

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-1_58.lib'

I tried the following things,

1. Include path is proper in header files. To confirm this I just typed BOOST_LIB_VERSION in one of the cpp file and while pressing F2, it took me to the version.hpp file of boost.

> #define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_70"

2. I just opened auto_link.hpp file of boost and I can see v141 toolset is enabled.

> define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc141"

3. In additional library directory I can see boost path is given. I gave absolute path too by suspecting on macro.
   $(THIRDPARTY_DIR)\boost\include

I expect V141 and correct boost library to be searched while linking.

Comment: do you have for some reason multiple boost directories for `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` and/or `AdditionalLibraryDirectories`? Also did you try to close all VisualStudio instances and restarted it again (sometimes the cache passed to MSBuild is not updated)? Also check the `Inherited value`s for these variables (had two versions of boost in different referenced property sheets that caused such behaviour).

Comment: exactly two version of boost is pointed in include directory. Thanks.

Comment: @Zaiborg Post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have multiple boost include directories added to the compiler input. Check Visual Studio's `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` variable (including its inherited values) to ensure only the desired version is included.

I did not copy-paste the comment because it was mainly questions. Here the 'answer' from your feedback :)